# How obtain Guard without facades (without static)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, non-static

Using static context (facades) the following code works:

```
$result = Auth::attempt(Input::only('email', 'password'));
```

Let's say I want to reduce static context to the minimum (which is said to be possible with Laravel).

I'm making a small compromise and get a reference to the application:

```
/* @var $app Illuminate\Foundation\Application */
$app = App::make("app");
```

... then get the auth manager:

```
/* @var $auth \Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager */
$auth = $app->get("auth");
```

Now the problem: `AuthManager` has no `attempt` method. `Guard` does. The only problem: Guard has no binding in the IoC ontainer. So how to obtain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AuthManager` inherits the `driver()` method from `Manager` which will give the a *driver instance* (which apparently is the Guard).

Also Manager uses magic to forward any calls to non-existent functions to the driver:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    return call_user_func_array(array($this->driver(), $method), $parameters);
}
```

So, to answer my own question:

```
/* @var $manager \Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager */
$manager = $app->get("auth");

/* @var $guard \Illuminate\Auth\Guard */
$guard = $manager->driver();
```

... but of course the interface won't guarantee that what you get is anything like the Guard. Just hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Dependency Injection and get it

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Guard as Auth;

public $auth;

public function __construct(Auth $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

public function doSomething()
{
    $this->auth->attempt(Input::only('email', 'password'));
}
```

and p.s. `Guard` is not a static reference - it is a facade which creates an instance when referred to. So you can still test etc. But that is a discussion for another time :)

Comment: Do I need some magic in the router to make this work? If I add a parameter to my constructor I get `'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard does not exist'`, if I add it to the controller method I get `Argument 1 passed to RpcController::get() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard, none given` (I'm using Laravel 4).

Comment: Whops - sorry - I was thinking of Laravel 5

Comment: I cant remember if it is `use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager as $auth` or `use Illuminate\Auth\Guard as Auth`. Try them both

Comment: `use Illuminate\Auth\Guard as Auth` compiles, but I'm getting `Illuminate\Container\BindingResolutionException' with message 'Target [Illuminate\Auth\UserProviderInterface] is not instantiable.`

Comment: AuthManager works. But my real problem was getting the Guard form the AuthManager. :)